# How to get time when session starts and finishes?

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I have a task to get the time when the session starts and finishes in Laravel. 
Is it I should use Laravel Websockets to accomplish this task of maybe Pusher?
What technology should I dive deeper into?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you don't need to go to `Websockets` or `Pusher`, you just need simple `setInterval` function to display session out time. And you will get session out time from `session.php` file inside config folder `'lifetime' => 120,` here 120 is minutes.

```
var sessionOutTimeInSeconds = 120 *60;
setInterval(function(){ 
    sessionOutTimeInMinutes -= 1;
}, 1000);
```

```js
var sessionOutTimeInMinutes = 2;// here your can set 120
var sessionOutTimeInSeconds = sessionOutTimeInMinutes * 60;
var timeStr = 'Expire in 120 Minutes';
var alertBefore = 1;
    var intervalId = setInterval(function(){ 
        sessionOutTimeInSeconds -= 1;
        sessionOutTimeInMinutes = parseInt(sessionOutTimeInSeconds/60);
        timeStr = '';
        // **here you can do any stuff when you got session out. may be you can redirect go to home page to go to login page.** 
        if(sessionOutTimeInSeconds > 0 ){
        if(sessionOutTimeInMinutes >= alertBefore){
            timeStr = '<span style="color:green;">';
          }else{
            timeStr = '<span style="color:red;">';
          }
          timeStr += 'Expire in '+ sessionOutTimeInMinutes + ' Minutes ' + (sessionOutTimeInSeconds%60) + ' Seconds';
        }else{
           //alert('Session Expired.');
           //clearInterval(intervalId);
           timeStr = '<span style="color:red;">';
           timeStr += 'Session Expired '+ (-1)*sessionOutTimeInMinutes + ' Minutes ' + (-1)*(sessionOutTimeInSeconds%60) + ' Seconds ago.';
        }
        
        timeStr += '</span>';
        document.querySelector('#sessionout').innerHTML = timeStr;
    }, 1000);
```

```html
<div id="sessionout"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

to get session start time:

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['started'])) {
    $_SESSION['started'] = $_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME'];
}
```

I'm not sure how to do session end time, but maybe you can use the same logic for it. Maybe this thread could be of some assistance for that: [When does a PHP session end?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20129774/when-does-a-php-session-end)