# Adding User Input to the Array

Tags: php, html, xampp

I am trying to take user input by form and add it to array. Basically, I have one form which has "name" and "description" fields, and "Submit" button. Every time user fills in the form and clicks the submit button, I want it to be added into array. Right now it takes input and stores it, but I have no idea how to add more names and description from the user without removing the existing ones.

This is my Form in HTML:

```
<form method="post" action="">
    <div class="row form-group">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <label class="sr-only" for="name">Project Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="project_name[]" id="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Project Name">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row form-group">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <label class="sr-only" for="desc">Project Description</label>
            <input type="text" name="project_desc[]" id="desc" cols="30" rows="10" class="form-control" placeholder="Project Description">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit">
    </div>
</form>
```

And this is how I display it:

```
<h2 id="admin_project_name">
<?php
    $project_names = $_POST['project_name'];
    foreach( $project_names as $key => $n ) {
      print "The name is ".$n;
    }
?>
</h2>
<p id="admin_project_desc">
<?php
    $project_desc = $_POST['project_desc'];
    foreach( $project_desc as $key => $d ) {
        print "The description is ".$d;
    }
?>
</p>
```

How I can implement what I want?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need sessions for this and/or JS.

Comment: You need to save them in database and then output as you need

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner OP does not say for how long it need to be saved. .. $_SESION data can be lost. ..

Comment: And you only have one `project_name` and one `project_desc` in that form. So unless you are adding bit dynamically to that page the `[]` arrays are achieveing nothing

Comment: @Ingus Well come to that so can data in a database :)

Comment: @Ingus How can sessions be lost?

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner Why you suggest if you do not know that?

Comment: @Ingus Errr... huh? Edit: Don't know *what?*

Comment: As I know, there is a "Push" function which does that, but idk if it's needed in my case. Is database strictly required?

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20129774/when-does-a-php-session-end

Comment: @Ingus I seriously doubt that by the time someone adds to the array, that the script would already have timed out. I am quite aware of how they work, *thanks*.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner Just saying. .. You do not know how often new add happens. ..

Comment: @Ingus And non of us know what the session timeout is set to, could be 1000's of second

Comment: @RiggsFolly True true!